# blueimp file upload. How to clean existing filelist

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I have goggled a lot, but have not found a solution for my issue. The author of the widget references to the last answer of FAQ, but the FAQ does not have the answer or I cannot find it. I suppose it was updated since that time. Other fellows who faced the same issue and asked the same question just gone and did not provide any solution.

Anyway, in my case I have a table with button Pictures:

[image]

When a user clicks one of pictures button, modal dialog is shown. The user now can manage pictures for the chosen row. He can upload, delete pictures and so on. When the user opens the dialog for second row in the table he should see pictures for the second row *only*. It tells me that I have to clean the list of uploaded files every time user hits Pictures button to see the dialog. He will receive list of pictures which corresponds to chosen row from the server. Unfortunately, when I retrieve the list for the chosen row, the received files are added to the existing list.

Could you tell me how I can clean the list or reset the widget without removing files on the server side?

**UPDATE** I have used the following piece of code as a temporary solution.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<YOUR URL HERE>",
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).done(function (result) {
        jQuery("#fileupload").find(".files").empty(); //this line solves the issue

        jQuery(this).fileupload('option', 'done').call(this, null, { result: result });
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

i was also trying for one hour to get my upload work ;)

here is, how i solved this problem:

```
$('#html5FileInput').fileupload({
    ....
    add: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var newFileDiv = $(newfileDiv(file.name));
            $('#fsUploadProgressHtml5').append(newFileDiv);

            newFileDiv.find('a').bind('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var uploadFilesBox = $("#fsUploadProgressHtml5");
                var remDiv = $(document.getElementById("fileDiv_" + event.data.filename));
                removeFileFromArray(event.data.filename);
                remDiv.remove();
                data.files.length = 0;
                ...
            });

            data.context = newFileDiv;
        });
     ...
)};
```

as you can see i create inside the add-event my file-dataset with 'newfileDiv(file.name)'. this creates a div with all information about the file (name, size, ...) and an ankor that exists for deleting the file from the list. on this ankor i bind a click-event in which i have the delete implementation.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it mean that there is no native and smart way (like call a method) to clean the list? Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the most elegant solution, but I needed a very quick and dirty...so here's what I did (using jQuery).

```
//manually trigger the cancel button for all files...removes anything that isn't uploaded yet
$('.fileupload-buttonbar .cancel').first().trigger('click');

//check the checkbox that selects all files
if(!$('.fileupload-buttonbar .toggle').first().checked) {
    $('.fileupload-buttonbar .toggle').first().trigger('click');
}

//manually trigger the delete button for all files
$('.fileupload-buttonbar .delete').first().trigger('click');
```

I know this isn't the best way. I know it isn't elegant...but it works for me and removes everything from the plugin.

If you have added file names or anything else from the plugin to any local arrays or objects, you'll need to clean those up manually (I have several handlers that fire on `fileuploadadded`, `fileuploadsent`, `fileuploadcomplete`, `fileuploadfailed`, and 'fileuploaddestroyed` events).

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function get_file_objects($iteration_method = 'get_file_object') {
    $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
    if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
        return array();
    }
    return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
        array($this, $iteration_method)
        //scandir($upload_dir)
        //File listing closed by Doss
    )));
}
```

there is a scandir function responsible for listing the files. just uncomment it like i have done above and your problem is solved. it can be found in the UploadHandler.php file.

Comment: I search all over for this simple solution to remove the images from the screen after uploading. Why it isn't mentioned anywhere in the docs is beyond me. This should be the #1 solution THANK YOU